# ¿Cuál es la linea que me crea los aleatorios?

Tags: c++

Disculpen,pero no estoy muy seguro de cuál es la linea de código o el bloque de código que me crea los elementos de formas aleatorias.Podrían decirme? ¿Acaso es `random_shuffle`?

```
// SimulacionLoto.cpp: define el punto de entrada de la aplicación de consola.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include<algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

cout << "Programa de generacion de numeros de la loto" << endl;
int n = 39;
int desde = 1;
int hasta = 39;
//Declarando variables.
int   i, tempcantidad, suma, repetir, min, j, aux, indice, a;
cout << endl;


//Semilla para que los aleatorios no se repitan.
srand(time(NULL));





//Crear las variables para el arreglo dinámico.
int* aleatorio = new int[n];



//El valor desde no puede ser mayor o igual que hasta.
if (desde >= hasta)
{
    cout << "El valor desde no puede ser mayor o igual que hasta" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
//Calcular cantidad de posiciones en el rango desde-hasta.
tempcantidad = 1 + (hasta - desde);
int* temp = new int[tempcantidad];

//Insertar valores ordenados (valores desde-hasta) en el arreglo temp.
suma = desde;
for (i = 0; i <tempcantidad; i++)
{
    temp[i] = suma;
    suma = suma + 1;
}
//Generar aleatorios hasta que el usuario decida salir.
repetir = 1;
while (repetir == 1)
{
    //Desordenar arreglo temp.
    random_shuffle(&temp[0], &temp[tempcantidad]);
    //Insertar valores temp en arreglo aleatorio.
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        aleatorio[i] = temp[i];
    }


    //Metodo de ordenamiento por inserccion
    for (i = 1; i<7; i++)

    {

        indice = aleatorio[i];
        a = i - 1;

        while (a >= 0 && aleatorio[a] > indice)

        {

            aleatorio[a + 1] = aleatorio[a];
            a--;
        }

        aleatorio[a + 1] = indice;


    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "        ----------------------------------------";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "                 SIMULACION DE LA LOTO   ";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "        ----------------------------------------";
    cout << "\n";
    for (i = 1; i <7; i++)

        cout << "                      Lugar " << i << " = " << aleatorio[i] << endl;



    cout << "\n";
    cout << "        ----------------------------------------";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "                 Hecho por Luis S. Batista T.   ";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "        ----------------------------------------";
    cout << "\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}










}
```

Comment: Ninguna línea en ese código genera números aleatorios, `random_shuffle` (como su nombre "[shuffle](https://translate.google.com/#en/es/shuffle)" indica) desordena valores en un contenedor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes 2 variables (Que están usadas como constantes):

```
int desde = 1;
int hasta = 39;
```

`desde` está funcionando como el valor mínimo aleatorio que puedes generar (O sea, un 1). Mientras que `hasta` funciona como el valor máximo (O sea, 39).

En este caso, tu lotería tendrá cualquier número dentro del rango cerrado [1-39].

---

Por otra parte, estás definiendo 2 listas de números:

```
int* aleatorio = new int[n];        // n = 39 (Sin embargo, con 7 estaría bien)
int* temp = new int[tempcantidad];  // tempcantidad es 39
```

Una de esas listas (`temp`) es usada en este bucle:

```
suma = desde; // "desde" valía 1, entonces suma vale ahora 1.
for (i = 0; i <tempcantidad; i++)
{
    temp[i] = suma;
    suma = suma + 1;
}
```

Lo que estás haciendo ahí es guardar todos los números desde 1 (`desde`) hasta 39 (`suma`) en la lista `temp`.

El desarrollo sería:

```
Para i = 0 tenemos suma = 1; temp[0] = suma = 1; suma se modifica a 2
Para i = 1 tenemos suma = 2; temp[1] = suma = 2; suma se modifica a 3
Para i = 2 tenemos suma = 3; temp[2] = suma = 3; suma se modifica a 4
...
Para i = 37 tenemos suma = 38; temp[37] = suma = 38; suma se modifica a 39
Para i = 38 tenemos suma = 39; temp[38] = suma = 39; suma se modifica a 40
Para i = 39, se rompe el bucle porque 39 no es menor que 39 (tempcantidad)
```

Entonces ahora `temp` es una lista ordenada con todos los números desde el 1 al 39 como se ve en el desarrollo.

Acá aparece parte de la magia:

```
//Desordenar arreglo temp.
random_shuffle(&temp[0], &temp[tempcantidad]);
```

Tal y como pusiste en el comentario, lo que estás haciendo es desordenar la lista de números que antes tenías ordenada (`temp`).

```
Antes temp[0] era 1, después de desordenar temp[0] podría ser 7
Antes temp[1] era 2, después de desordenar temp[1] podría ser 34
...
Antes temp[37] era 38, después de desordenar temp[37] podría ser 12
Antes temp[38] era 39, después de desordenar temp[38] podría ser 23
```

Ahora es cuando empiezas a usar tu otra lista; la lista `aleatorio`. En este lugar:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    aleatorio[i] = temp[i];
}
```

El bucle llega hasta `7`, así que lo que estás haciendo acá, es tomar los primeros 7 números que se encuentren en la lista `temp` (Que ahora ya está desordenada) y los estás guardando en la lista `aleatorio`. (*Por eso puse en un comentario que si era `int* aleatorio = new int[7];` ya estaría bien, porque no estás guardando más que 7 números*).

```
Ahora aleatorio[0] ahora es temp[0] que podría ser 7.
Ahora aleatorio[1] ahora es temp[1] que podría ser 34.
...
Ahora aleatorio[5] ahora es temp[5] que podría ser 2.
Ahora aleatorio[6] ahora es temp[6] que podría ser 17.
El resto de los números en la lista temp quedan sin usar.
```

**Quedando la impresión de que tu lista `aleatorio` está formado por números aleatorios que generaste**.

Más adelante en tu código, ordenas los 7 números de la lista `aleatorio` y la muestras.

### Resumiendo:

> *Simulaste* haber generado 7 números aleatorios, cuando *técnicamente*
>   **NO los generaste**.   Generaste una lista de números ordenada *exactamente desde el 1 al 39*, **los mezclaste** usando
>   `random_shuffle` y mostraste los primeros 7 valores en orden.

---

Si realmente quisieras generar un número aleatorio, podrías usar la función `rand()` (*No confundir con* `srand()`)

Comment: En pocas palabras solo creo una lista de 39 números y con la funcion random_shuffle los desordena(los 39 números que tomo)y los muestra como si fueran aleatorios,sacando solo 7 de ellos?

Comment: Sip. Intenté resumir eso al final de la respuesta en el cuadradito naranja... Parece que fallé :p

Comment: No hay problemas.Ya entendi. Muchas gracias.!!

Comment: "*creo una lista de 39 números y con la funcion random_shuffle los desordena(los 39 números que tomo)y los muestra como si fueran aleatorios,sacando solo 7 de ellos?*" No. La afirmación correcta es "Creo una lista de números del 1 al 39, en ese orden, y los desordeno con `random_shuffle` quedándome con los 7 primeros y descartando el resto".

Comment: Son ciertas las observaciones de @PaperBirdMaster. Edité el resumen en la respuesta teniendo en cuenta las mismas.